# using an anonymous function with array_fill

Tags: php, anonymous-function

So my goal is to create a string of random letters, and the letters can be repeated in the string. So I thought I could be clever and do this:

```
$str = implode(
  array_fill(0,10,
    function(){ 
      $c='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
      return (string)$c{rand(0,strlen($c)-1)};
    }
  )
);
echo $str;
```

But I am receiving the following error:

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class Closure could not be converted
>   to string in ...

This is literally the only thing in my script, so no, it's not something else.  Now, the manual states 3rd arg description for `array_fill` is "Value to use for filling", and it's listed as accepting a mixed type. Now I know that "mixed" does not necessarily equate to "any" type, but it *seems* reasonable to me that that I should be able to use an anonymous function as a 3rd arg, as long as it returns a string, right?  But apparently I can't do this..

So, I'm not necessarily asking *why* I can't do this; it very likely boils down to the powers-that-be simply not writing it into the code under the hood.  But I guess I just wanted to double check that I did this code "right" in the sense that it "should" work if php allowed for it (but doesn't), vs. maybe I somehow messed up somewhere else?

Comment: it won't work because you are passing a function not a value. it doesn't matter that the function returns a value unless it's executed. before that its just a means to a value.

Comment: You can simulate what you're trying to achieve by using functions that do accept a callback: `$str = implode(
  array_map(
    function($value){ 
      $c='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
      return (string)$c{rand(0,strlen($c)-1)};
    },
    array_fill(0,10,NULL)
  )
);
echo $str;
`

Comment: @MarkBaker yeah that's basically what I came up with instead, while waiting for replies. I'm gonna give solve to IMSoP though because a) you didn't post an answer! and b) He explained where exactly the error was coming from. thanks!

Comment: Your question was about the error, and @IMSoP had already answered that... all I did was provide a simple alternative to your basic code which didn't actually answer the question, so it wasn't worth posting as an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without an explicit variant of the function, there is no reason to expect a function to **execute** your callback, rather than simply leaving it as a variable.

Let's break down the logic a bit:

```
// Declare the callback
$something = function(){ 
  $c='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
  return (string)$c{rand(0,strlen($c)-1)};
}
```

Regardless of what this function does, we now have a variable which happens to be a `Closure`.

```
// Fill the array
$list = array_fill(0,10,$something);
```

The array is now full of 10 copies of `$something`. That happens to be 10 pointers to our `Closure`. There's no reason for PHP to think that that's not what you want.

```
// Join up the items in the array to make a string
$str = implode($list);
```

Now, `implode()` has to make a string, so it converts each item in the array it's given to a string before proceeding. For an object, it will try to call `__toString()` (or the equivalent "under the hood" for built-in objects), but `Closure` has no such method. This is where your error is coming from.

So, no, you haven't messed up exactly, but it's not reasonable to assume that PHP will execute a callback just because you know that's what you want.

---

As [Mark Baker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/324584/mark-baker) points out in a comment, you can use `array_map` to execute your callback; reusing `$something` from above, and breaking it down for clarity:

```
// Create 10 items, with nothing interesting in them
$list_of_nulls = array_fill(0, 10, null);

// Run the callback for each item of that list
// It will be given the current value each time, but ignore it
$list = array_map($something, $list_of_nulls);

// Now you have the list you wanted to join up
$str = implode($list);
```

Of course, you could also just run the function 10 times in a loop:

```
$str = '';
for ( $i=0; $i<10; $i++ ) {
    $str .= $something();
}
```

Comment: Ah, thanks for the explanation of where the error was actually coming from; this makes sense. I had come up with an alt much like Mark's comment, but your explanation helps me sleep better at night, thanks!

Comment: also, yeah.. I somehow got it in my head that doing something involving a callback would be less code and more clever looking but it'd be a lot less code to just use a regular loop and `$str.=..` I guess I just got carried away trying to be clever :/

Comment: Ah, yes, the temptation of the clever and fashionable vs the short and simple, I know it well! ;)

Answer (score 3):

This can be done with [array_fill](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill.php) and [array_map](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php):

```
$number_of_items = 25;

$array = array_map(function() {
  // Your callback here
  return 'foo';
}, array_fill(0, $number_of_items, null));
```